# Xamarin Forms - include a parameter on the clicked event of a button

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

What is the best way to add a parameter to the Clicked event of a button in Xamarin Forms?
For the button below I would like to send the button text as the parameter to SetPinNo in code-behind

```
<Button BackgroundColor="Teal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="White" BorderRadius="1" TextColor="White" Text="1" Clicked="SetPinNo"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also suggest you to go with `MVVM`. You can set `PINNO` in `ViewModel`. Create `PINNO`property with backing field in `ViewModel` as:

```
string pinNo="";
public string PINNO
{
    get { return pinNo; }
    set
    {
       pinNo=value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now bind the Button `Text` to PINNO and `command` as

```
Text={Binding PINNO} Command={Binding PinButtonCommand}
```

In ViewModel define the Command as

```
public ICommand PinButtonCommand { get; private set; }
```

In the `Constructor` of `ViewModel`

```
PinButtonCommand=new Command(Dosomething);
```

Finally the method to execute whenever the PinButton is Clicked

```
void Dosomething()
{
    //Use the PINNO Property here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use `MVVM`, set the `BindingContext` of your `ContentPage` to a `ViewModel` and bind your button's to `Command` and a `CommandParameter`. So you could send whatever is needed as a `CommandParameter`, keeping your UI and business logic completely separated.

There is a [very nice article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/#Commanding_with_ViewModels) about MVVM and data bindings in official guides about it.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use commands, the event handler has an `object sender` parameter. Cast it to a button and you can extract the text.

```
var button = (Button)sender;
var text = button.Text;
```